# Repeat values in fixed number of rows in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, row, repeat

I have a dataframe **DF1** consisting of 168 file names:

```
DF1$FileName <- c("File1.csv", "File2.csv",..... "File168.csv")
```

Using:

```
filez <- NULL
for (i in 1:168){
     filez[i] <- paste0("file", i, ".csv", sep="")
}
filesz <- as.data.frame(filez)
```

I have another dataframe **DF2** as follows:

```
DF2$RowNumber <- as.data.frame(rep(c(1:512000), times = 168, length.out = NA, each = 1))
```

This means DF2 has a column "RowNumber" in which there are 168 times repetition of numbers 1 through 512000 (i.e. total 86016000 rows).

What I want to do is to:

1. Select a file name (one at a time) -> DF1$FileName[i]
2. And repeat paste it 1 to 512000 in DF2$FileName
3. Repeat the above untill all 86016000 rows have filled in

The end result should look like:

```
DF2
RowNumber     FileName
1             File1.txt    
2             File1.txt
3             File1.txt
.             .
.             .
.             .
.             .
512000        File1.txt
1             File2.txt
2             File2.txt
3             File2.txt
.             .
.             .
512000        File2.txt
1             File3.txt
2             File3.txt
3             File3.txt
.             .
.             .
512000        File3.txt
.             .
.             .
512000        File167.txt
1             File168.txt
2             File168.txt
3             File168.txt
.             .
.             .
512000        File168.txt
```

I tried this, but I know there is logical mistake leading to system hanged up:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(m)){
    while(m$RowNumber[i] != 512000) {m$FileName[i] <- filez[[i]]}
}
```

Can someone please suggest me better and easy way to resolve my issue?

I am sure R would have some package to perform such operations, but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a `for` loop in this case. You can use specifically designed functions for that, like:

**1)** `expand.grid` from base R:

```
filenames <- paste0("file", 1:168, ".csv")
rownumbers <- 1:512000

d <- expand.grid(rownumbers = rownumbers, filenames = filenames)
```

which gives:

```
> head(d)
  rownumbers filenames
1          1 file1.csv
2          2 file1.csv
3          3 file1.csv
4          4 file1.csv
5          5 file1.csv
6          6 file1.csv
```

**2)** The `CJ` (cross join) function from the *data.table* package:

```
library(data.table)
d <- CJ(rownumbers = rownumbers, filenames = filenames)
```

which will give you the same result.

**3)** The `crossing` function from the *tidyr* package:

```
library(tidyr)
d <- crossing(rownumbers = rownumbers, filenames = filenames)
```

which will also give you the same result.

Comment: Hi Jaap. Thanks for the solution. but i guess, it should be :     df1 <- expand.grid(rownumbers, filenames)  which resolves my issue.

Comment: @MANU By using `rownumbers = rownumbers` you make sure that the columns will be named directly. If that is not necessary, using `df1 <- expand.grid(rownumbers, filenames)` or `d <- CJ(rownumbers, filenames)` will suffice.

Comment: @Japp: Suppose I still have to pick one at a time filename from DF1, how the code should look ? I will have to use Loop, right?

Comment: @MANU Why would you do that? Using a for-loop is infinitely slower in this case.

Comment: '@Japp Yes Mate, Thanks. What I did was a small tweak around your code:  **filenames <- files; rownumbers <- 1:512000; df1 <- expand.grid(rownumbers=rownumbers, filenames=filenames$NewName);
View(head(df1, n=20));** and it worked well. Really easy way.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this would be with integer division so:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(m)) {
    filenum = 1+floor((i-1)/512000)
    filename = paste0("File",filenum,".txt")
    ## instead of : m$FileName[i]=filenum , use:
    m$FileName[i] = filename  ## it works!
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Suppose, for some reasons, I can't use **filename = paste0("File",filenum,".txt")** within the for loop as in your suggestion, how I should call **filename <- DF1[i]** (i.e. one filename at a time from other dataframe) for repeating it into loop?